# Python pickle on list

Tags: python

Im trying to store a list in a flat file through and for some reason I dont see the file being created..under c:\python27\basics\db.txt

Here is my code:

make_db_pickle.py

```
from Basics import data
import pickle

db = data.people

dbfilename = 'c:\python27\Basics\db.txt'

try:
    dbfile = open('dbfilename','wb')
except IOError as (errno,strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected Error", sys.exc_info() [0]

pickle.dump(db,dbfile)
dbfile.close()
```

data.py

```
bob={'name':'bobs mith','age':42,'salary':5000,'job':'software'}
sue={'name':'sue more','age':30,'salary':3000,'job':'hardware'}

people={}
people['bob'] = bob
people['sue'] = sue
```

Comment: `'c:\python27\Basics\db.txt'` Ugh. Don't do that. :( Use raw strings or proper escaping. One day you'll make some small change to the path (such as changing the filename to `test.txt`) and wonder why it stopped working.

Answer (score 5):

Are you expecting the file 'c:\python27\Basics\db.txt' to be created? When you call open, you give it a filename of 'dbfilename'. I don't think you want quotes there. Check if the file is being created, but in the same directory as where you're running the script from, and under the filename 'dbfilename'.

So, if you ran this script under 'C:\MyStuff', check for the file 'C:\MyStuff\dbfilename'.